# Flutter - Fix Drawer Header

Tags: dart, flutter, navigation-drawer

Following this link [Add a Drawer to a screen](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/drawer) I have created a drawer.

Following is my piece of code:

```
// FUNCTION CONTAINING LEFT SIDE MENU ITEMS
  _drawerList() {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'John Doe',
                ),
              ],
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/menu_bg.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            // Some Code
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // Some Code
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: _drawerList(),
        ),
        // Some Code
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can fix "DrawerHeader" so that it doesn't move with the drawer and list view.

P.S. I don't want to hold ListView. I just want to hold or fix "DrawerHeader".

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm stuck on this too.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, move it out of the ListView widget and use Column to hold both DrawerHeader and ListView.

**With items scrolling enabled**

```
_drawerList() {
  return Drawer(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        DrawerHeader(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'John Doe',
              ),
            ],
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/menu_bg.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              // Some Code
            ),
            ListTile(
              // Some Code
            ),
            ListTile(
              // Some Code
            ),
            ListTile(
              // Some Code
            ),
            ListTile(
              // Some Code
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

**With items scrolling disabled**

```
_drawerList() {
  return Drawer(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        DrawerHeader(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'John Doe',
              ),
            ],
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/menu_bg.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          // Some Code
        ),
        ListTile(
          // Some Code
        ),
        ListTile(
          // Some Code
        ),
        ListTile(
          // Some Code
        ),
        ListTile(
          // Some Code
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I dont want to hold ListView. I just want to hold "DrawerHeader"

Comment: Why not holding the ListView? Maybe you will have many ListTiles and they wont be visible on smaller device...

Comment: Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Cannot hit test a render box with no size.

Comment: First code throws an exception, 
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 323 pos 12: 'child!.hasSize': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of wrapping inside ListView you can wrap it inside column and then add other widget inside that. Also if you want to divide header and other part in any ratio you can use Expanded widget.

```
 _drawerList() {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: DrawerHeader(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'John Doe',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: ListView(

                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                title: Text("Ses"),
                // Some Code
              ),
               ListTile(
                title: Text("Ses"),
                // Some Code
              ),
               ListTile(
                title: Text("Ses"),
                // Some Code
              ),
               ListTile(
                title: Text("Ses"),
                // Some Code
              ),
               ListTile(
                title: Text("Ses"),
                // Some Code
              ),
               ListTile(
                title: Text("Ses"),
                // Some Code
              ),
               ListTile(
                title: Text("Ses"),
                // Some Code
              ),
               ListTile(
                title: Text("Ses"),
                // Some Code
              ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to pin DrawerHeader on top with fixed height and make list to fill rest of space below.

```
final drawer = Drawer(
    child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
      Container(
          height: 200,
          child: DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
              child: Text('Right Drawer Header',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24)))),
      Expanded(
          child: ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, children: [
        ListTile(leading: Icon(Icons.message), title: Text('Message')),
        ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle), title: Text('Profile')),
        ListTile(leading: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text('Settings')),
      ]))
    ]));
```

[image]